Prove $\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{r\binom{n}{r}} = \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{n-r}r}$ if n is a positive integer
I've considered using induction but I struggle to see how to induct over the choose function. I want to use combinatorial reasoning but I understand that's unlikely due to the fact that there's fractional components on the LHS and RHS. I've tried manipulating the algebra but it doesn't seem to work. I get to the point $\sum \frac{(r-1)!(n-r)!}{(n!)} = \sum \frac{2^{r-n}}{r}$

Ok that answer requires such heavy machinery I don't UNDERSTAND
